# Does the turtlebot power/gyro board need to enable the kinect?

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do I need to 'turn on' the turtlebot power/gyro board somehow to power up my kinect? I see it get power momentarily as I turn on my iCreate but it powers off immediatly after.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11487/does-the-turtlebot-power/gyro-board-need-to-enable-the-kinect?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you do. The Create needs to be put in "full" mode to enable the breakers. This can be done by using the Mode button on the [TurtleBot dashboard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_dashboard), or by sending it motion commands (using one of the [teleoperation examples](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_teleop/Tutorials/Teleoperation) or your own code).

If it's still not working when it's in full mode, use the dashboard to check that breaker 0 is set. Breaker 0 should automatically be set, though.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.